# Standard cmd line separation for option-arguments

Tags: python, command-line, posix, gnu

Is there a standard for how command-line arguments are passed, or does this differ from program to program? For example, here are a few examples:

1. `$ script.py -a 2`
2. `$ script.py -a=2`
3. `$ script.py a=2`
4. `$ script.py --all 2`
5. `$ script.py --all=2`

Comment: check out `argparse`. It will support I think 1, 4 and 5.

Comment: @alani thanks, it seems it supports all but `#3`. Is there one option that is 'most standard' ? Or it depends from program to program?

Comment: There's a most-POSIX-standard way, and there's a most-GNU-standard way. Something that complies only with POSIX standards won't acknowledge `--all` at all; see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02 for the letter of the spec. (One important difference: In the POSIX world, all options have to be before any arguments; in the GNU world, it's usually also permissible to put options _after_ positional arguments -- "usually" because the `--` end-of-options sigil is still honored in the GNU world).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy -- I see, so the `-a 2` would be the most universal perhaps?

Comment: ...as for `a=2` with no leading dashes, it's not an option under _either_ POSIX or GNU conventions, so it's normal for it not to be recognized by any option-parsing library.

Comment: Yes, `-a 2` is about as generic (and thus, widely compliant) an approach as you can get.

Comment: `$ script.py -a2` also works (if the option accepts one argument - the default case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `argparse`, you will find support for most of the above options. For example:

```
# test.py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Dedupe library.')
parser.add_argument( '-a', '--all', nargs='+', type = int, help='(Optional) Enter one or more Master IDs.')
```

To run:

```
df$ python test.py -a 2
# {'all': [2]}
df$ python test.py -a=2
# {'all': [2]}
df$ python test.py a=2
# test.py: error: unrecognized arguments: a=2
$ python test.py --all 2
# {'all': [2]}
$ python test.py --all=2
# {'all': [2]}
```

As you can see, all are supported except the form of `script.py a=2`